# RadioButton Alignment in a Grid

Tags: bugs, front-end, gui-construction, grid-layouts

**Bug introduced in V10.4 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

Since 11.3 it is even worse as it stays there despite of clicking.

> CASE:3910286

---

```
Grid[{{
   RadioButton[]
 , Framed[1, ImageSize -> {100, 100}]
}}, Alignment -> {Left, Center}]
```

[image]

Alignment is off unless I click it twice:

[image]

Workarounds are not difficult, feel free to add your ideas.
The main reason for this question is to not forget and to put pressure on fixing all those annoying bugs.

Win10 V11.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I feel free to add mine:

```
Grid[{{Column @ {RadioButton[]}, Framed[1, ImageSize -> {100, 100}]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) I had `Framed` with `FrameStyle->None` but this is shorter :)